# Build android app with unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I would like to build a unity3d project to android app. i have installed all android sdk but i got always this error

> Failed to re-package resources.

And below the console logs :

> Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.android.gms -S "C:\Users\ousla\Documents\WorkspaceUnity\TestApp\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res"
>   stderr[ ] stdout[
>    Configurations:
>    (default)
>    v11
>    v21

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Plugin conflict/problem.

Copy your **google-play-services_lib** folder to your project's **Plugins/Android** folder.

OR

**Remove** **all** your Plugins at **Plugins/Android** then **re-import** them but uncheck 
**google-game-palay services_lib** folder when **re-importing** them.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  I think that the problem is with android sdk, Unity3d didn't support yet API 24 cause I tried it with Api earlier than 24 and it works.

Comment: Well you didn't write that you were using API 24. Unity added support for API 24 after the 5.4.0 Beta 11 release. Download it from here http://unity3d.com/unity/beta/archive

Comment: it's mentioned in the log console that i'm using api 24. Thanks i will download it ;)

Comment: Reading the whole log is like reading software **Terms of services**. Most of the time, only the first line of the log is what you need to pin-point the problem. Let me if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unity is running aapt.exe from build-tools/24.0.0 ( you can see the path of aapt.exe in the log). Version 24 is for Android N (the next upcoming version Android), which is not supported by Unity at the moment (many developers are complaining about this exact issue).

In order to resolve this issue, you have a few different options:

Under your Android SDK folder, remove version 24.0.0 of build-tools (sdk/build-tools/24.0.0).

You can do the same from the Android SDK manager (select build tools version 24 and then "delete package")

SDK manager

In case you need that version specifically, you can install another Android SDK that will only be used with Unity. In this installation, do not include build-tools 24.

Lastly, you should try to upgrade to the latest Unity version, as this issue should be solved (I believe it was solved in 5.3.5p4).